# Как реализовать обратную последовательность с неизвестным числом?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, математика, шифрование

Я пытаюсь зашифровать информацию, пока в виде простых чисел но я плохо разбираюсь в математики
Хочу узнать ваши мысли или идеи по поводу этого.

идея такая я беру простые числа и математически складываем их

```
1 + 1 = 2
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 2 = 5
5 + 3 = 8
8 + 5 = 13
13 + 8 = 21
21 + 13 = 34
34 + 21 = 55
```

теперь я делаю обратно тоже самое, я знаю только два числа `34` и `55`, зная эти числа я получу все остальные.

```
55 - 34 = 21
34 - 21 = 13
21 - 13 = 8
13 - 8 = 5
8 - 5 = 3
5 - 3 = 2
3 - 2 = 1
```

Теперь что я пытаюсь сделать

мне надо в эту комбинацию добавить еще одно уникальное число. уникальное это значит неизвестное число, оно может быть любым.

```
1 + 4? + 1 = 6
6 + 7? + 1 = 14
14 + 8? + 6 = 28
28 + 3? + 14 = 45
45 + 9? + 28 = 82
82 + 1? + 45 = 128
128 + 2? + 82 = 212
212 + 6? + 128 = 346
```

теперь я снова пытаюсь сделать обратную последовательность, но дело в том что я не знаю какое число скрыто где знак `?` сейчас там `6`

```
346 - 212 = 134
```

как видите я не знаю правильное число, мне нужно получить число `128` и `6`, а я могу получить только `134`. Но я не знаю не того не другого числа что бы получить оба варианта, даже если я буду знать что там `6` на данный момент

```
134 - 6 = 128
```

то следующее число я так же не смогу расшифровать, я снова не знаю какое число спрятано внутри, в данном случае там число `2` и `82` но я знаю только `84`.

```
212 - 128 = 84
```

Меня интересует, если ли метод который позволит мне так манипулировать с числами, или это математически не возможно, что я пытаюсь тут вам показать.

Comment: Да просто пишите любые числа подряд - их тоже будет невозможно расшифровать...

Comment: Вы можете расшифровать первую последовательность так как знаете правило, по которому она строится (числа Фибоначчи). В остальных случаях закономерность найти будет сложнее. Может почитать про метод конечных разностей.

Comment: Я так понимаю что вы считаете что это невозможно.
А если случайные числа будут от 1 до 9 тогда можно как то точно определить что это за число?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ладно, смотрите: если два разных исходных текста шифруются в одну и ту же последовательность, то это уже не шифрование, а хеширование :) Вы *принципиально* не можете выяснить, что подано на вход, если разные входы дают один выход.

Как вы понимаете, последовательностей гораздо больше, чем можно записать одним или даже двумя числами. Но, чтоб было проще - вот конкретные примеры трех разных последовательностей, приводящих по вашему алгоритму к одной и той же паре чисел 100 и 159:

```
  1 + 6 +  1 =   8      1 + 8 +  1 =  10       1 + 7 +  1 =   9
  8 + 9 +  1 =  18     10 + 7 +  1 =  18       9 + 6 +  1 =  16
 18 + 8 +  8 =  34     18 + 5 + 10 =  33      16 + 8 +  9 =  33
 34 + 5 + 18 =  57     33 + 7 + 18 =  58      33 + 9 + 16 =  58
 57 + 9 + 34 = 100     58 + 9 + 33 = 100      58 + 9 + 33 = 100
100 + 2 + 57 = 159    100 + 1 + 58 = 159     100 + 1 + 58 = 159
```

Думаю, это достаточная демонстрация, что ваш метод работать не станет?

Для однозначной расшифровки информации в зашифрованном тексте должно быть не меньше, чем в исходном.

P.S. По вашей просьбе числа от 1 до 9 :)

Comment: А других способов нету сделать то что я хочу?
может есть какой то способ определить число по двум другим числам

Comment: Ну смотрите - у вас есть (пусть числа - по 1 цифре) последовательность цифр. которую надо зашифровать. Из N чисел. Т.е таких разных последовательностей - 10^N. Т.е. чтоб однозначно расшифровать - должно быть минимум N-значное (в десятичной записи) число. И от этого никуда не деться...

Comment: Получается можно только перебирать число N и то не факт. Могу ли я как то закрепить результат перебора, что мое число N верное прежде чем я начну перебирать следующее число?
Или это тоже не возможно.
Например 2 найденных числа могут закрепить перебор числа N в очереди 3

Comment: Например зная все 3 числа можно получить точный ответ
100 - 57 - 34 я точно знаю что там 9
проблема скорее в том что мне не узнать число 34 пока я не знаю число 9.

Comment: Вы не с той стороны начинаете... Ну, как те, которые квадратуру круга ищут или там вечный двигатель...